# ContentControl view not updating when changed outside of ViewModel constructor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

My ContentControl in my MainMenuView will update when I set it in the constructor, but not after that. I'm trying to get it to change on button click. The command appears to be working and changes the values of my CurrentPageViewModel. I'm following this code example for changing the view https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/.

MainMenuViewModel:

```
public MainMenuViewModel()
    {
        SelectViewCommand = new RelayCommand<IPageViewModel>(s => ChangeViewModel(s));
        PageViewModels.Add(new ClockViewModel());

        CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[1];
    }
    private List<IPageViewModel> pageViewModels;
    public List<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels
    {
        get
        {
            if (pageViewModels == null)
                pageViewModels = new List<IPageViewModel>();

            return pageViewModels;
        }
    }

    private IPageViewModel currentPageViewModel;
    public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get { return currentPageViewModel; }
        set { currentPageViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("currentPageViewModel"); }
    }

    public RelayCommand<IPageViewModel> SelectViewCommand { get; private set; }

    private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
            PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

        CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels
            .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null)
        {
            changed(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

MainMenuView:

```
<Window x:Class="TextApp.View.MainMenuView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextApp.View"
    xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:TextApp.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainMenuView" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:ClockViewModel}">
        <local:ClockView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:IPageViewModel}">
        <local:IPageView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectViewCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Margin="2,5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: In the setter of your `CurrentPageViewModel` property you are notifying for your backing field `currentPageViewModel` instead of the property. I'd try updating that and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: Hey, I just tried it. It didn't work.

Comment: You view model does not implement INotifyProperytChanged.

Comment: I created a sample app and it seems to work for me, but I filled in some pieces that aren't in your supplied code. Can you update your question with the full view model class as you have it now?

Comment: Hey, I forgot to respond. I forgot to implement from INotifyProperytChanged. It is working now.